# Can't retrieve 3rd party json data

Tags: jquery, json

I was trying to retrieve some 3rd party (external site) json data. I thought this would work, but for some reason it doesn't...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JSON Test</title>      
</head>  
<body>
...

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/415/2013/11/22/fi?callback=?", function(data){
            alert(data.meta.generated_timestamp);
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use JSONP. http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: @Leke there is something wrong with callback. are you sure you're using JSONP ? http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/22/

Comment: Yep, with the jsonp, I tried the example in jquery4u with the ?callback=? and ?jsoncallback=?, but I just noticed there is a missing ; on the external json file. Would that block the data import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any information on sodexo.fi, but even though you are using `?callback` (which makes jQuery use JSONP instead of a normal XMLHttpRequest) you need cooperation from the server to give you the correct JavaScript back as well.  sodexo.fi does not do this -- at least not for the requested URL.

Additionally, it does not set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to allow for CORS (which would also let you get around using JSONP).

Unless you can find a JSONP API that sodexo.fi exposes, your only option is to have another server that hosts your front end and also acts as a proxy for these JSON requests.

Comment: I haven't really worked with json before, but the file's json formatting without the ; looks correct. So I guess you are saying that the server needs to be serving the file as json instead of whatever it is currently serving it as. This is why the error is being reported - (because jquery expects oftype json).